# Are there good online resources for the easy translations?

Tags: traduction, ressources

Given that [site policy](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/translation-questions) is veering away from 'simple' translations (if such a thing exists!), which on-line resources would you advise people to use?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Quelques dictionnaires explicatifs (donnant le sens des mots en français), c'est toujours bien de vérifier le sens des mots donnés par les dictionnaires bilingues.

- http://atilf.atilf.fr/ le Trésor de la Langue Française informatisé (malheureusement les liens vers l'intérieur du site sont temporaires)
- http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ (une série de dictionnaires dont une version du Trésor de la Langue Française informatisé -- avec des liens permanents mais un système de recherche moins puissant que l'interface du lien précédent --, quelques dictionnaires de l'Académie française, ...)
- http://www.larousse.com/fr/dictionnaires/francais-monolingue
- http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ N'oubliez pas Wiktionary, par les personnes qui vous apportent Wikipedia.

Quelques dictionnaires des synonymes:

- http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/des/ le Dictionnaire électronique des synonymes
- http://www.synonymes.com
- http://www.dictionnaire-synonymes.com
- http://www.cnrtl.fr/proxemie/ outil donnant une représentation graphique des rapports entre synonymes.

Une liste de dictionnaires bilingues:

- http://www.wordreference.com/fren/
- http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/
- http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/fr/index_tr.html (une version bilingue français-anglais d'un outil de proxémie semblable à celui du cntrl)
- http://dict.leo.org/frde?lp=frde&search= (entre français et allemand)
- http://www.larousse.com/fr/dictionnaires (les dictionnaires Larousse)

Finalement une liste de service de traduction en ligne:

- http://translate.google.com/
- http://www.online-translator.com/
- http://translate.reference.com/
- http://frengly.com/
- http://www.linguee.fr/ (utilise le web comme source de traductions d'expressions et donne des liens vers l'expression et sa traduction en contexte)

Les dictionnaires [Le Robert](http://www.lerobert.com) ont des versions en ligne, mais payantes.

Pour du vocabulaire plus spécialisé :

- [Le Grand dictionnaire terminologique](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/) de l'Office Québécois de la Langue Française dans tous les domaines
- [le glossaire](http://glossaire.traduc.org/index.php) de traduc.org dans le cas de l'informatique.

Une astuce pour des expressions ou du vocabulaire spécifique est d'utiliser wikipedia en recherchant l'entrée correspondante dans la langue connue et puis utilisant la possibilité de trouver l'entrée dans une autre langue.

---

Certaines entrées de cette collection proviennent d'autres réponses et parfois d'autres questions. N’hésitez pas a compléter, c'est déjà mis en CW.

Comment: WordReference est une très bonne ressource.

Answer (score 12):

http://www.linguee.fr is great for human translations of common and even not so common phrases within the context they occur, it searches translations that are on the web.

Answer (score 7):

Pour ajouter à la liste d'[@Un francophone](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/176) je conseille de visiter [frengly.com](http://frengly.com/) - facile et qui traduit bien à mon avis.

To add to the list of [@Un francophone](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/176) I would recommend [frengly.com](http://frengly.com/) - easy to use and it seems to work well enough for most things - providing that you can read enough to spot the typical machine translation faults.

Answer (score 5):

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) is a pretty good resource for easy translations.

[The translator](http://translate.reference.com/) of Dictionary.com can be a good one too

Comment: Google Translate must be used very wisely, sometimes it translates good, other times completely wrong.

Comment: @Alenanno : yes, but you can evaluate google translations and submit some better ones if you want.

Comment: That's the main reason why it's not 100% reliable. **Everybody** can submit a different choice, so both experts and people who might make it wrong on purpose... :D You never know...

Answer (score 4):

As well as [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/), I like to see [PROMT's](http://www.online-translator.com/) rendering of translations too, which I often find better.

Answer (score 4):

Pour traduire entre français et allemand, je conseille [LEO](http://dict.leo.org/frde?lp=frde&search=).

Answer (score 4):

I use [www.wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com)

It contains many definitions and usages... Works for many languages back and forth.

Answer (score 3):

For single words, I have had some good results with [a Dutch](http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/vertalen.php?s1=&s2=EN+%3E+FR&s3=EN+%3E+FR&woord=cute) [online dictionary](http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/vertaal/EN/FR/lemming) - go figure. It does work way better if Dutch is involved, but English to French doesn't work that bad either, and sometimes you get definitions of the words too, which I think is a great help.

In any case, if by any chance you need Dutch <-> French, it'll be a good reference (you didn't specify source language in your question).

And, even if your question specifically says "online", I'll pretend I didn't see it and mention the good old-fashioned dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

J'aime beaucoup l'[Atlas sémantique](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/fr/index.html) - (not sure if it still works, requires Java Applets)

Comment: Pas mal.  Ce format évite les problèmes des dictionnaires bilingue trop simples dans lesquels on a du mal à trouver le mot juste.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Google Chrome browser, it has translation built in.  When you open a page that's primarily in any language other than your default, the browser detects it and puts a bar across the top of the page asking if you'd like the page translated.  After translating, you can hover your mouse over any sentence to view the sentence in the original language.

Comment: I've already found this very useful browsing around here on French SE.