# How do I discuss the fireplace in French?

Tags: vocabulaire

Can anyone tell me the French words for *chimney*, *fireplace*, *mantelpiece* and *hearth*? Because my dictionary, Google Translate and Babelfish translate all these words to *Cheminée* which makes for a ridiculously imprecise conversation.

How does one distinguish between these words in French?

Comment: You may want to steer away from "translating" tools and use a real dictionary. See also [this question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/402) on online resources for translations, including dictionaries.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google is not wrong here, *cheminée* is an accurate translation for all your words. If you want to be more precise, though, you can use

- *foyer* : fireplace
- *âtre* : hearth
- *manteau de cheminée* : mantelpiece
- *conduit de cheminée* : chimney (the whole pipe)
- *souche de cheminée* : chimney (the visible roof structure)

Comment: I didn't mean to say that Google is incorrect, just that when you're trying to discuss this topic, having the same word for every piece of the puzzle makes it a touch um... vague :P Thank you though, I really appreciate your help.