# Downloadable French dictionary

Tags: ressources, dictionnaires

I've been searching for a while for finding a French-to-French dictionary and I found nothing.
Is there any good such dictionary?

**Note:** I want to use it on my laptop like longman, **I do not** need any printed dictionary because I can not use any (they're big).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about the French language.

Answer (score 8):

**Le Littré** is a well known french dictionary, download its freeware [here](http://code.google.com/p/dictionnaire-le-littre/).

**Le Robert** is another well known french dictionary, you can download it [here](http://www.lerobert.com/decouvrez-gratuitement-nos-dictionnaires.html) (10 days trial).

Comment: Or you could try XMLittré at http://francois.gannaz.free.fr/Littre/accueil.php if you don't want to download anything.

Comment: The link  francois.gannaz.free.fr/Littre/accueil.php does not work anymore.

Comment: On ne peut plus télécharger Le Littré par le lien http://dictionnaire-le-littre.googlecode.com/files/Littre-windows-2.0.exe

Answer (score 7):

I find [Antidote](http://www.druide.com/a_description.html) to be a great electronic dictionary. It contains twelve dictionaries, eleven grammar guides, a powerful spellcheck and other useful information like synonyms, antonyms, conjugation tables and cooccurrences (words that work well together). It is a bit expensive though.

Comment: +1 for this awesome tool. I had a lexicology teacher who'd use it every now and then while teaching, for additional insights on his examples.

Answer (score 2):

Some ressources linked [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/405/176) comes from providers having a standalone version.

Comment: Thanks but I don't need online resource:(

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Franqus](http://franqus.ca), a web french dictionary made in Quebec (contains more informations about French American words).

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this [wiktionnaire.mobi](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NRb2qGOb3wdDFzd0M4b01WWFU/view) ie the french wiktionary exported.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca), a French dictionary  from Canada.