# How is the 'root' of the verbs referred to?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

I would love to know what is the correct term to define the 'root' part of the verb, which is usually the part kept in tact whilst transforming the verb into other tenses.

e.g.

```
verb = manger
root = mang-
```

Thank you.

Comment: A simple lookup in  a standard ressource like those given [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/402/176) will give you the [answer](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/root). If you have still problems after such a lookup, please explain it in more details.

Comment: Pull up the [Wikipedia article in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_%28linguistics%29) and check out the [corresponding article in French](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_%28linguistique%29).

Comment: @Phil As per the [FAQ#questions], we ask that you look in a dictionary before asking a question. If you still have a question after that step, we can help you. Since your question was readily answerable by looking in a dictionary, it was closed.

Comment: Kareen, this is was not intended to be dictionary-check or quick-translation question. I am a native speaker of both French and English languages. I know what the word "root" means in both and in a several more. What I didn't know was the LINGUISTIC term. I did not even know I had it right with "root" in English, which I used to ask the question. Doesn't make sense to look something up without knowing. The comments above are egoistic and self-satisfactory, serving to nothing. Thank you though for clarifying. And I thank with all my heart to @Stamm for showing the decency of not being a smarty.

Comment: @Phil I voted to close your question, but I didn't understand you were looking for specific terminology. Maybe you could edit your question and be more clear about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root part is called “racine” or “[radical](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_%28linguistique%29)”.