# Meaning of toilette

Tags: vocabulaire

In some 19th Century texts that I've been reading, the word "toilette" is used in a way that doesn't seem to mean "toilet".

Such as: "lui fit remarquer la vieillerie de la toilette de madame de Bargeton".

Everywhere I look online, I can only find a meaning synonymous with the english word "toilet"... Does it have another meaning?

Comment: For you next searchs, all the resources cited [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/405/176) that I checked had the correct answer available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"toilette" in the context you specified (noun) is used in a similar way to "outfit".

You can find some entries on [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/toilette/78290).

> Ensemble des vêtements et des accessoires portés par quelqu'un.

Other uses as noun [Dictionary reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/toilette) include getting clean and/or groomed depending on the context.

Although... I also noticed that the English dictionaires have the definition of "toilette" as meaning "outfit", for instance [FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/toilette).