# The verb "manquer" used with the impersonal pronoun "il"

Tags: verbes

> *Il s'agissait d'une ravissante fille à qui il ne manquait qu'un brin de toilette pour paraitre vraiment sensas.*
>
> **From San-Antonio Chez Les Gones**

I'm having a lot of difficulties translating this sentence, especially concerning the grammar here.

I know it must mean sth around: *it was just a delightful girl who missed only a tidy-up to appear terrific.*

But the (..une fille à qui il ne manquait qu'un..) part confuses me.

First, there's *il manquait*. Its literal translation should be: he missed. But who is he?

Then there's *à qui* which I have no idea why it's placed in the sentence in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I** No, no "he" here, you are dealing with the impersonal "il", which, as its name implies, has nothing to do with persons.

- Il manque une roue à cette voiture. (*There is a wheel missing on that car.*)

*A better example, as the English will tell even better what is the idea*

- It is raining. (*You would never think of saying "He is raining".*)

**II** "À qui" is a grammatical word that allows you to introduce a clause; that clause is a relative clause because the grammatical term contains a pronoun that you call relative; in your sentence its antecedent is "fille"; in other words it replaces girl; this way you can rewrite this as follows, but then it is not correct grammar because nothing connects the two clauses.

- Il s'agissait d'une ravissante fille à qui il ne manquait qu'un brin de toilette pour paraitre vraiment sensas.

Here "qui" is "complément d'objet indirect"; that's required by the verb. However you can use a construction as in English with the subject pronoun.

- Il s'agissait d'une ravissante fille  qui n'avait besoin que d'un brin de toilette pour paraitre vraiment sensas.  (*You just change the verb, and you have your subject pronoun.*)

Answer (score 7):

Your translation is not bad, I'd maybe use **lack** instead of **miss**.

The pronoun ***il*** in *il ne manquait* is impersonal, it doesn't represent anyone or anything. It's just the verbs *manquer* and "miss" aren't necessarily used the same way in French and English. e.g.:

> *Il me manque une carte*

> I'm missing a card.

See also [this reply](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/983/1109).

Then, ***à qui*** is composed of the preposition ***à*** (from) because it is used with *manquer* here: *Il **manque** quoi **à** la fille ?* and the pronoun ***qui*** that refers to the girl, i.e the person who is lacking something.

Instead of ***à qui***, the form ***[à laquelle](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19806/why-the-need-to-use-%C3%A0-laquelle-in-one-part-and-then-%C3%A0-qui-in-another/19809#19809)*** could have been used:

> *Une fille **à laquelle** il ne manquait qu'un brin de toilette.*

***À qui*** often translates to "**to whom**":

> *[À qui de droit](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2249/1109)* → To whom it may concern

Finally, *[**toilette**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toilette)* is likely a play of words because it can mean both "grooming" and "nice female [outfit](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6455/meaning-of-toilette)".

Here is my translation:

> **She** was just a delightful girl who was only **lacking** a little **neatness** to look terrific.

or better, thanks to Luke:

> She was a lovely girl who was only a little [grooming|neatness|freshening up] away from being stunning.

Comment: "She was a lovely girl who was only a little neatness away from being stunning." But not quite satisfied with "neatness". Maybe "freshening up" (depending on whether the author means a little *toilette* is needed right now or in general). One could say "cleaning up" but that's only used of men...

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agissait d'une ravissante fille à qui il ne manquait qu'un brin de toilette pour paraitre vraiment sensas.

From San-Antonio Chez Les Gones

In terms of *translation into English*, here is how to parse the French:

- il manque quelque chose dans la maison = something is missing in the house, notice the reversal in English [impersonal usage]
- *quelque chose manque **à** quelqu'un*: someone is missing something, also a reversal in English

*il manque* in French **can be** impersonal in the sense that *il* does not refer to a subject. It functions impersonally. So, to translate you take the object or thing that comes after the verb manquer and make that the subject in English.

Here, the young lady was missing a bit of grooming

à qui: of whom, literally, will disappear in English because it is French structure:

*X manque à quelqu'un* becomes: X [a person] is missing something.

- Il s'agissait d'une ravissante fille à qui il ne manquait qu'un brin de toilette pour paraitre vraiment sensas.

*il ne manquait qu'un brin de toilette*=

*REVERSAL*:

- only a bit of grooming was missing for her to look really sensational.

Note: in English, we don't use groom much anymore due to the negative connotations re child abuse. However, here it does work.

Other verbs: fixing up, tidying up, etc. In other words, her look was not put together. Most likely her hair and nails.

Now the first part: Il s'agissait d'une etc. cannot be translated using the usual: This concerns or this is about, here. So, let's take the ravissante fille and do this:

Translation:

1. She was a very beautiful girl who was only missing a bit of grooming (or cleaning up or tidying up etc.) to look really sensational.
2. She was a very beautiful girl who only needed to be cleaned up a little to look really sensational.

The first shows the process but is a bit awkward; 2) is smoother and the term missing disappears, too.

ravissante could also be: ravishingly beautiful but that is more unusual in English.

A bit of a tidy-up is fine too.

In English, you hear: You clean up well, to mean that a person looks nice when they are dressing up.