# Présumer vs supposer ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Quelles sont les différences et les nuances entre ces deux mots, présumer et supposer ?

Pour donner un peu de contexte qui pourrait aider, je cherche l'équivalent du mot anglais "assume" comme il est plus souvent utilisé aujourd'hui (dit autrement, pas l'usage qui correspond au mot français "assumer").

Comment: I can't help with your main question, but regarding how to translate "assume," I usually end up by using the appropriate form of either "penser" or "croire." That might end up by generating the French equivalent (if any) of the "That's what you get for thinking" snarky retort but it's a bit better than the "ass" of "you" and "me" thing, imo.

Comment: Assume is faire une hypothèse

Comment: J'aime bien [cet outil](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/fr/index_tr.html) (voir [cette réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/405/176) pour d'autres choses disponibles) même s'il est parfois d'un abord difficile (en particulier la langue de départ a un effet qui fait qu'il est parfois intéressant de lancer l'outil dans les deux sens; autre chose, il faut jouer avec les axes pour ne pas avoir une vision tronquée).  Il permet en effet de voir comment différents termes dans les deux langues ont des sens qui se recouvrent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Le mot présumer sous-entend le risque d'erreur** dans ce qu'on suppose comme tel. Quand je présume un fait, je considère ce fait probable, voire très probable. Mais cela reste une probabilité et peut être incorrecte.

**D'autre part supposer un fait consiste a prendre celui-ci comme hypothèse, comme prémisse d'un raisonnement ou d'une démonstration, comme base d'un ensemble d'autres faits qui découleront de cette supposition**. C'est le cas par exemple de certaines suppositions non vérifiées dans certains raisonnements mathématiques à partir desquels découlent pourtant d'importants résultats.

Celui qui présume quelque chose le fait en ayant à l'esprit le risque de se tromper, une telle personne pourra dire en cas d'erreur qu'il avait présumé "honnêtement" la chose ou le fait. Alors que celui qui suppose fait abstraction de ce risque d'erreur (au moins temporairement) afin d'utiliser le fait supposé ou la chose supposée pour s'en servir comme outil permettant d'établir un autre fait une autre chose.

le mot anglais "assume" est plus proche de supposer ('assume' anglais est utilisé par exemple en raisonnement mathématique en lieu et place du supposer français). Le traducteur google français anglais traduit incorrectement assumer français en assume anglais alors que le même traducteur utilisé dans le sens anglais français traduit correctement assume anglais en supposer français.