# Resources and References - 2023

Tags: grammaire, expressions, ressources, dictionnaires

I was curious about resources (in particular free internet resources) that other people use on this site to research their answers to French usage/grammar questions. I am primarily interested in reputable references beyond what a basic Google search could yield.

I found these (several are overlapping in scope):

- [Lexilogos](http://www.lexilogos.com/francais_langue_dictionnaires.htm)
- [Dictionnaire Littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/)
- [Dictionnaire Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/)
- [Reverso](http://www.reverso.net/text_translation.aspx?lang=EN)
- [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire:Page_d%E2%80%99accueil)
- [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/)
- [Dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://atilf.atilf.fr/academie.htm) and [Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/)
- [French language links from Oxford University](http://www.lang.ox.ac.uk/links/french.html)
- [ARTFL at University of Chicago](https://artfl-project.uchicago.edu/)
- [DVLF](https://dvlf.uchicago.edu/)
- [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/)
- [Office québécois de la langue française](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/accueil.aspx)
- [Outils et ressources linguistiques du gouvernement du Canada](http://canada.pch.gc.ca/fra/1449590953720)
- [Dictionnaire de la Zone](http://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/)
- [Langue française](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Accueil/Introduction) (and its [forum](http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/))
- [Occitan](http://www.panoccitan.org/) and [Etymologie occitane](http://www.etymologie-occitane.fr/)
- [Orthonet](http://orthonet.sdv.fr/)
- [Usito](https://%20%20https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/)
- [Les expressions du monde francophone](https://%20%20https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/les-expressions-du-monde-francophone/)

For frequency of usage of words, expressions in books:

- [Google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams)

This one is the "ultimate" for usage, but it is not free. There is an online version too:

- [Le Bon Usage](http://www.lebonusage.com/)

This is one that all students in France know about, mostly for conjugations, but it now covers orthography and grammar too:

- [Bescherelle](http://bescherelle.com/)

This one is a free resource geared towards learning French, containing exercises, dictionaries, conjugation tools and more:

- [francaisfacile](http://www.francaisfacile.com/)

A list of words that can be used for computer processing:

- [dicofr](http://www.pallier.org/ressources/dicofr/dicofr.html)

A "lexique" with some statistical data:

- [Lexique3](http://lexique.org/)

Scanned dictionaries, including old ones:

- [dicfro](http://micmap.org/dicfro/dictionaries)
  40 online searchable dictionaries including 18 **Old French** dictionaries.
- ***[Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/accueil/fr/content/accueil-fr?mode=desktop)***
  The digital library for online users of the *Bibliothèque nationale de France* and its partners. To this days it has more than 6 million digitized materials of various types: books, magazines, newspapers, photographs, cartoons, drawings, prints, posters, maps, manuscripts, antique coins, scores, theater costumes and sets, audio and video materials. All library materials are freely available.
- [**La *Grande Grammaire du Français***](https://www.grandegrammairedufran%C3%A7ais.com)
  Published in 2021. Includes data from contemporary written French, but also  data from spoken corpora and regional or non  standard  French.  Throughout  the  grammar,  a  simple  phrase structure  grammar  is  used,  in order  to  maintain  a  common  representation.
  Print and online subscription (many institutions will have subscribed)

---

What other similar resources exist out there? In particular, I am interested in resources/data about the frequency of usage of words, expressions, etc. in France.

Comment: I don't post answers, but: (a) http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/ (b) http://www.linguee.fr/ (c) https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire:Page_d%E2%80%99accueil

Comment: @Catomic - thanks - I'll add some of your links to my post so it's easily visible for people coming to this page.

Comment: Is it possible to make wiki posts on French SE ? This one could be a good subject.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - please upvote if you like the question :-)

Comment: @Frank: french pupils uses bescherelle in schools for more than 40 years. L’un de ces livres contient d’ailleurs tout les verbes conjugués de la lange française. Tout les écoliers on un jour utilisé ce dernier.

Comment: Oui, j'en ai 3 a la maison :-) de mon temps on n'en avait qu'un pour les conjugaisons, mais maintenant il y en a deux de plus, pour la grammaire. Je vais mettre un lien sur l'edition papier et regarder s'il y a une edition online.

Comment: What about LAROUSSE?? Bilingual and monolingual. I am having issues getting to it but it is accessible and free. (downvote that like every one of my posts, just about). Linguee is not really a dictionary. It is a half-assed compilation that can only be used reliably by people who already know the languages. It is not reliable.

Comment: What about TERMIUM??

Comment: There are very good tools apparently on the parent page of the Termium page, and I will add that. For Termium itself, I would need to spend more time to fully get it: from my cursory use of it, it appeared to return mostly very short definition from 1 or 2 sources, maybe oftentimes geared towards the needs of Canadian government translators? (I could be wrong)

Comment: Also, French in Québec is sometimes not exactly French in France (probably a stupid truism). Absolutely not a problem, just need to be aware of it.

Comment: Resources lists are **not** questions and should be wiki answers on Meta. The list should be classified by type or resource and preferably with a description.

Comment: @Frank TERMIUM est une excellente source de terminologie avancée et technique. Et souvent, ceux qui travaillent dans la traduction technique en France l'utilisent. Cela ne veut pas dire que chaque terme  est exactement le même en France. D'autre part, ne pas mettre le Larousse dans une liste comme celle-lá et mettre Linguee me semble une aberration.

Comment: @Lambie - Larousse y est... par l'intermédiaire de Lexilogos... En fait, comme il y a des "aggrégateurs" dans la liste, il faudrait que je fasse le tri et que j’enlève les duplications, ou bien que "j'aplatisse" les "aggrégateurs".

Comment: @Lexilogos ne veut pas le coup. Il faut mieux ne pas mettre des "aggrégateurs", à mon avis.

Comment: Lingolia is perhaps too basic for serious research, but it presents the same material in French and English (and other languages). French: https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/grammaire / English : https://francais.lingolia.com/en/grammar

Comment: Did anyone point you to this earlier compilation? http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/402/are-there-good-online-resources-for-the-easy-translations/405#405

Comment: Règles de typographie française
https://framasoft.org/article2225.html

http://www.weblettres.net/exos/index.php

Comment: I use Larousse.fr a lot, but I'm not sure what content it has grammar-wise.

Comment: Le lien dicofr est rompu

Comment: https://www.deepl.com/translator  est aussi très pratique, et propose une liste de mots quand on clique sur un des mots traduits, plus fiable que le Reverso (très peu de propositions inadéquates)

Answer (score 3):

Great idea !

I think you have absolutely to add https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/

As a french, I personally used it when I have doubt

Comment: Legit and useful - adding it :-)

Comment: I think Frank should refrain from adding this private (for profit) resource to his list.

Comment: After reading your comment, I would said that's wrong because Projet Voltaire had some blog article that talk about somes common mistakes as " ça / ca / sa " or " à / a " and more exemples, but I searched those articles and they seem to not exist anymore, so if you want to delete this ressource, I will be totally agree. You can replace it with http://www.francaisfacile.com/

Comment: Hmmm - yeah, if it's for profit, it's not too great. I'll probably replace with francaisfacile.com then. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: As a french? I think private here is no good.

Comment: Private? They publish all kinds of stuff publicly on https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/actualites/ I've never seen the private side of things, but there's plenty of useful stuff like http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/%C2%AB-vingt-%C2%BB-ou-%C2%AB-vingts-%C2%BB (although they seem to have broken their old links just yesterday but it's still there in principle)

Comment: @None on devrait tout consolider dans le premier poste et enlever les réponses?

Answer (score 2):

I use a number of the resources you listed as well, perhaps most often Linguee.

I'm sure you're aware of this because of its prominence on Google searches, but my personal list also includes [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/). It has a few very helpful features, including easily disambiguated definitions that differ by part of speech, precise sense, formality level, etc., as well as frequent collocations. Most entries also include a link to one or more forum posts at the bottom where people of varying closeness to the language offer their opinions on grammar and usage questions. It also includes the Collins dictionary, pronunciation, and conjugation ready to hand. One of the weak points in its reliability is its example sentences, though. Since you mentioned that you're looking for resources that deal with usage in particular, the number of WR forum posts about a given entry can be a good indicator, in my experience, for estimating the appropriateness of a particular term, and perusing a few threads and taking the average opinion in them can help balance out any one site's analysis of a question.

Of course, the principle of taking large samples from a wide variety of sources and gleaning any consistencies you can find after cancelling out the nonsense applies no matter the resource. :)

I'm not sure if you have to deal with technological subjects in your French usage, but I also find Microsoft's bidirectional [Language Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/language/en-us/Search.aspx?langID=fr-ca) a handy reference for frequent computer terms. They have a bunch of variations of each term listed by program.

Comment: I have added WordReference.

Answer (score 2):

La nouvelle version du DVLF vient de sortir : https://dvlf.uchicago.edu

Voici l'annonce qu'a fait l'équipe :

> The ARTFL Project at the University of Chicago is delighted to announce
>   the release of version 2.0 of the Dictionnaire Vivant de la Langue
>   Française (DVLF). The DVLF is an experiment in French community
>   lexicography. While the DVLF offers many traditional lexicographical
>   resources, including definitions from several historical French
>   dictionaries, it also allows users to add words, definitions, usage
>   examples, and other types of information to the site. Additionally, the
>   DVLF features a tool that provides users the opportunity to vote on the
>   perceived quality of example sentences taken from the project's corpus
>   and, in the process, rank the examples in real time.
>
> The new version of the DVLF offers a much improved service with faster
>   performance, new collocation and associated words data, expanded
>   examples, and a new responsive web UI. We invite you to visit the site,
>   and we welcome your feedback at dvlf@artfl.uchicago.edu.
>
> Thank you,
>
> The DVLF Development Team (Tim Allen, Charles Cooney, Clovis Gladstone)
>   and ARTFL (Dir. Robert Morrissey, Asst. Dir. Mark Olsen)

Je n'ai pas trop utilisé cette ressource, mais après avoir fait un premier essai je crois qu'elle sera utile.

Comment: Très clair avec beaucoup d’exemples d’emplois contemporains qui ouvrent l’accès à un langage soutenu

Answer (score 2):

Je crois que aucun n'a mentionné le site Orthonet.

http://orthonet.sdv.fr/

Je le trouve vraiment super.

Comment: Intéressant pour la saisir l’environnement des mots, qui les emploie,  toutes les analyses qui se rattachent à un mot, le choix du code phonétique excepté.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/les-expressions-du-monde-francophone/

Un guide linguistique franco-québécois et pour les expressions du monde francophone.

Answer (score 1):

https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/

> Usito, un dictionnaire conçu au Québec pour tous les francophones et
> francophiles intéressés par une description ouverte du français.