# Any tips for learning french?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, vocabulaire, usage, prononciation

I am learning french via duolingo and was simply wondering if there are any tips or tricks to learn the language better for I’ve been having trouble remembering different possessives and other similar words and such. Just looking to learn better.

Comment: Have you learned a language before? If remembering things is your current stumbling block, I would look into a spaced repetition system to help you remember, like Anki notecards. When I was first learning basic words, I used to write them all down every couple of hours throughout the day, maybe in chunks of 20-30, from memory until they were all deeply set.

Comment: @Aerovistae other than learning my first language, I’ve never learned a new language. Also I have heard of Anki but duolingo implements this through mastery testing where you practice weak words as you go. I meant more like memory devices and other tricks I can use to help make the knowledge more concrete.

Comment: Please go to language learning SE

Comment: @Cloud alrighty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your mother language is English. First of all, Internet offers a plethora of options. To name but a few (all free):

[BBC courses](https://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/french/index.shtml)

[LawlessFrench](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/)

[ToLearnFrench](https://www.tolearnfrench.com/)

They provide everything a beginner should know. You should buy a good grammar book. There are many great books and Amazon is a good place to find used ones at affordable prices. Personally, I highly recommend the book [Easy French Step-by-Step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071453873), a best seller for anglophone learners of French, which has the advantage of a very reasonable price. The only drawback I see, is the lack of an accompanied CD for the pronunciation but you can certainly deal with it by watching French tutorial videos in YouTube. Of course the aforementioned links contains relevant material.

In addition, buy a good French-English, English-French dictionary. There are online dictionaries, but it is a good practice to have always available a hard copy.

If you have forgotten basic grammatical terms I suggest you to buy the book
[English grammar for Students of French](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0934034427)
One has to grasp English grammar (or their mother tongue grammar for that matter) before attempting to learn the French one.

If you cannot afford many books don't worry, you can find a glossary of the basic grammatical terminology (accusative, dative, personal pronouns and the like) usually in the form of an appendix in almost every grammar book for learning French. The aforementioned appendices are most often accompanied by the French counterparts. I.e.

> Imperfect=Imparfait, Perfect=Passé Composé, Pluperfect=Plus-que-parfait, Past Historic=Passé Simple, Accusative/Dative=Complément d'Object Direct/Indirect, etc.

Of course, as always, Internet offers information about almost everything ([glossary](http://www.gccd.ie/files/Anderson1e_GramTerms.pdf)).
But personally being a little archaic, I prefer the hard copies:-)! Thus, I suggest also a [French Reference Grammar like that of H. Ferrar (Cambridge University Press)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/French-Reference-Grammar-H-Ferrar/dp/0199120331/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1522143868&sr=8-1&keywords=french%20reference%20grammar) which has the advantage of being irresistibly...cheap (used copy).

If you are a student, you could apply for the [Erasmus program](http://www.erasmusprogramme.com/country.php?country=France) and asking ways to pass a semester in France. Staying a period in France will help you to make leaps and bounds with the French language very quickly .
In addition, find either an advanced learner of the french language or even better someone who is French native speaker to talk with.
Also, another suggestion is to find someone that has the same level with you in French (and the same goals as well, linguistically speaking!) and work together.

Last but not least, post your questions here:-)! Good luck with the so called langue de Molière; an amazing language indeed.

**EDIT**

Other online ressources:

https://www.culture.gouv.fr/Sites-thematiques/Langue-francaise-et-langues-de-France/La-DGLFLF

https://www.binge.audio/category/parler-comme-jamais/#

https://www.binge.audio/category/parler-comme-jamais/#

https://www.telerama.fr/radio/binge-audio-donne-un-coup-de-frais-a-linfo,n6127814.php

Comment: Very useful answer! Merci!

Comment: @AshtinBlanchard Je vous en prie ! I want also to add this thread https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24262/resources-to-verify-french-words-expressions-usage-grammar

Comment: that’s a great link I’ll keep that around

Comment: @AshtinBlanchard See also the Edit that I made to my reply.