# Ressources du français familier

Tags: registre-familier

Le but de cette question est tout d'abord comme [celui-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24262/resources-to-verify-french-words-expressions-usage-grammar), mais pour la partie du français dit non-standard (familier, informel, etc.).
Je suis intéressé par des livres ou des sites internet. La plupart des livres que je possède ne présentent pas des tournures françaises telles que

> Où y sont ?, faut que j'y aille, ça va aller, filer, etc.

Je désire donc que cette question devienne une collection de ressources pour ce sujet. Par exemple en faisant une recherche google j'ai trouvé

http://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/usage/familier/1/

http://lexiquefle.free.fr/banlieue/vocabulaire.pdf

Enfin et surtout pourquoi existe-t-il ce décalage entre le français standard et le français familier?
Je ne sais pas si cette dernière question est trop vaste. Le cas échéant, je peux l'enlever.

Comment: A good question but probably too vast and fundamental to all of language. Where do colloquial forms come from? Many possible sources. Phonetic trends (simplification of /il/ to /i/). Regularization of exceptional forms (*kneeled* instead of *knelt*). Popularization through literature or media (KJV Bible preserving *thee*, *dost*, etc.). Playfulness in comedy. Misanalysis of surface forms by children (*an apron* instead of *a napron*). Miscommunication by inconsistent teachers. Natural semantic shifts (metonymy, antiphrasis, etc.). And probably a few more!

Comment: So the question of where it comes from in general is probably not answerable. Asking where particular forms come from, yes — like I recently asked in chat about a user's "et bien jammy" and was pointed to the show "C'est pas sorcier". That'd be one per question. If this question is seeking sources that list common expressions, it's more answerable, though list questions don't always fare well. Anyway, I'll be interested to see what others think.

Comment: Merci pour les deux comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il faut que vous précisiez votre recherche sur google en ajoutant le mot "[argot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argot)" pour trouver plus de résultats.

J'ai par exemple trouvé ces deux dictionnaires en ligne: [1](http://mondouis.pagesperso-orange.fr/) et [2](https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/). Le deuxième est mieux présenté je trouve et plus actuel. Il vous permet aussi d’accéder à un riche éventail de vocabulaire de mots utilisés dans le langage familier en retournant les mots, ce que l'on appelle le [verlan](https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/dictionary/verlan).

Je recommande toutefois l'usage des mots familiers avec modération et en connaissance de cause. Si j'étais vous je regarderai des vidéos et des films en français de type grand public dans lesquels vous trouverez d'innombrables expressions et de mots ayant parfois des sens différents de ceux que vous avez pu apprendre.

Attention toutefois, la langue évolue continuellement! Nombreux sont les mots que j'ai pu lire dans les références que vous avez mentionnées (ainsi que les miennes) que je n'avais jamais vu auparavant. Certains ne sont sans-doute (au premier sens du terme, i.e., sans aucun doute) utilisés que dans des régions ou des villes en particulier, d'autres à mon avis absolument désuets et à bannir.

On n'apprend pas une langue simplement en apprenant par cœur des mots et des expressions, il faut aussi pratiquer; l'écoute (vidéos, films, chansons, ...) est très importante au même titre que la possibilité de parler régulièrement avec des personnes natives du pays de la langue que l'on apprend.

---

Pour la question :

> Enfin et surtout pourquoi existe-t-il ce décalage entre le français standard et le français familier?

Je répondrai que c'est la même chose dans toutes les langues. Je ne sais pas de quelle origine vous êtes, mais prenez l'anglais par exemple, moult (i.e. beaucoup de) mots d'anglais familier sont "très" différents de ceux qu'on leurs préfère lors d'usages plus soutenus.