# Is there any table for French grammar - question words and more?

Tags: grammaire, ressources

I'm looking for a grammar table in French that explains

1. Question words
2. Common phrases
3. Basic verb rules
4. Basic way to say "it, some, any..." etc.

Is there any a table or large picture for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources to verify French words, expressions, usage, grammar](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24262/resources-to-verify-french-words-expressions-usage-grammar)

Comment: @livresque not really. I'm looking for a picture or a table with words and phrases only

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily expect all of this to be in a single table, since it encompasses a variety of topics (and not necessarily ones that fit a single table well). To a degree, verb rules can be condensed, perhaps, but even ["any"](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/any/562730) doesn't have a straightforward translation.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us a sample of such a table in the language of your choice, so we can understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made one for French conjugation. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1S0lrEDn7nK6iJxC7q1Nj6LQNWHilmXTqxzRQvj3eBCc/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the table in pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/21788)

Answer (score 1):

You would find all grammar tables in French within the book entitled "[La Nouvelle Grammaire en tableaux (NGT)](https://www.multidictionnaire.com/produits/grammaire/)" by Marie-Éva De Villers, ordered alphabetically according to the word in question.