# Préposition après « valoir mieux pour qqn » (Via Mala, de John Knittel, Albin Michel, p. 419)

Tags: prépositions, expressions-idiomatiques

> *Via Mala*, John Knittel
>
> — Enfermer mère? répéta-telle stupéfaite.
> Elle s'obstine tellement à vouloir aller à l'église qu'elle ne parle plus de rien d'autre. Et si on la quitte de l'œil, elle descendra tout droit à Andruss.
> — Mais pourquoi ne la laissez-vous pas?
> — La laisser?
> Niclaus rit amèrement.
> — Elle irait tout droit au confessionnal. Non, nous ne pouvons pas la laisser se débarrasser de son fardeau, de cette manière égoïste. Et il vaut mieux pour elle être enfermée à la maison que dans la prison de Lanzberg.

Il existe un préposition usuelle que l'on trouve il me semble immanquablement après « valoir mieux pour qqn » ; c'est « de » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vaut+mieux+pour+vous+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3), [exemples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vaut%20mieux%20pour%20vous%20de%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)). L'usage sans « de » (où une autre préposition que personnellement je ne connais pas), si rare puisse-t-il  être, existerait-il ? Y a-t-il une autre préposition que l'on puisse utiliser au lieu de « de » (je pense surtout à « à », mais les ngram ne donnent rien) ?

Comment: L'ajout de "pour quelqu'un" n'intervient  pas dans la syntaxe  classique de "il vaut mieux être *adjectif ou participe passé*". Exemples : https://citation-celebre.leparisien.fr/citation/il-vaut-mieux-etre

Comment: @Graffito Si vous pouvez fournir des exemples sans la préposition, vous avez une réponse. Il est certain que si « pour qqn » n'est pas dans l'expression il ne faut pas de préposition.

Comment: Dans le lien que j'ai indiqué, les exemples sans préposition devant le verbe  sont nombreux ; "il vaut mieux être seul que mal accompagné".

Comment: @Graffito Ce n'est pas ce que je veux dire. Il faut prouver que l'expression avec « pour qqn » peut être utilisée sans préposition.  Il me semblait tellement que ce n'était pas possible que je n'ai pas vérifié « vaut mieux pour vous être ». Je viens de le faire et, surprise, je trouve qu'en fait c'est vrai, mais vieux et très rare de nos jours. Voilà le lien : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vaut+mieux+pour+vous+%C3%AAtre%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr — Vous pouvez faire la réponse si vous le désirez. Si personne ne la fait, eh bien je la ferai peut-être plus tard.

Comment: @LPH Pas besoin de "preuve". Il y a simplement ce que les gens disent ou ne disent pas et la langue évolue. Très peu de gens utilisent la langue en faisant des raisonnements basés sur la grammaire. "il vaut mieux pour elle être enfermée" et "il vaut mieux pour elle d'être enfermée" me semblemt parfaitement acceptables. La première expression est un peu plus légère à mon avis.

Comment: @Frank Ce qui vous semble et ce que c'est peuvent être deux chose différentes ; en derniers avis lorsque l'usage ne peut pas être déterminé à partir d'information tangible on en restera sur de telles conclusions (untel pense que c'est acceptable). Cependant le système de question réponse du FSE n'est pas de la sorte ou on se contente d'impressions pour les questions et p)our les réponse. Il a toujours été demandé que des références d'une sorte ou d'une autre soient citées dans les réponses. Vous dites que les deux sont acceptables, mais les pages d'exemple montrent que c'est très rare (1/2)

Comment: @Frank de nos jours dans le cas de la construction sans « de ». Je vous rappelle que les ngram servent de référence qui sont reconnues (comme étant acceptables) dans les avis aux utilisateurs. (2/2)

Comment: @LPH - Ce n'est pas une impression. C'est l'usage vivant qui me sert de référence, et cela a une valeur aussi. Dans l'usage pratique et courant, personne ne détectera d'erreur ni dans une version ni dans l'autre, à moins qu'il ne s'agisse d'un exercice à la Bernard Pivot. Vous pouvez insister pour vouloir qu'une seule des deux versions soit la seule "correcte", mais la langue vivante n'en a cure.

Comment: @LPH Même s'il existe une version "correcte" dans une grammaire donnée, un auteur pourrait très bien choisir une forme qui sonne mieux, et ignorer la grammaire. "Il vaut mieux pour elle être enfermée" me sembler sonner bien mieux que la version avec "de". Ce "de" est un obstacle à la fluidité de la "liaison" "ell-être".

Comment: @LPH J'ai également posé la question à plusieurs français éduqués au niveau universitaire autour de moi, et pas un n'a mis en avant la grammaire, et aucun n'arrivait à se décider. C'est une donnée valide (et limitée à la taille de l'échantillon, bien entendue) sur l'usage courant.

Comment: @LPH L'usage vivant et le ressenti de francophones (ils sont d'ailleurs très variés!) doit être accepté comme une référence, sinon, FSE peut être remplacé par une liste de "références" bien connues, dont j'avais d'ailleurs compilé une liste iciM https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24262/resources-to-verify-french-words-expressions-usage-grammar/41826#41826.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145222/discussion-between-lph-and-frank).

Answer (score 1):

Les deux possibilités se trouvent depuis au moins le 19<sup>e</sup> siècle jusqu'à nos jours, et pour ce qui est du cas du  pronom « elle », en fréquence inférieure lorsque la préposition est utilisée. On trouve les deux cas aussi pour les autres pronoms et d'autres verbes que « être », comme on peut s'en douter (mais les listes d'exemple ne sont pas mentionnées ci-dessous).

En conclusion on peut dire que pour le pronom « elle » et le verbe « être » la construction avec la  préposition « de » n'est pas utilisé aussi souvent que celle sans.

[vaut mieux pour elle être](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vaut%20mieux%20pour%20elle%20%C3%AAtre%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) : à peu près une trentaine de cas (rééditions non comptées)

[être/valoir mieux pour elle d'être](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mieux%20pour%20elle%20d%27%C3%AAtre%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) : à peu près une trentaine de cas (rééditions non comptées)