# When is "ct" silent?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique

I am not usually surprised by French pronunciation anymore at this point, but every now and then I still stumble into something I realize I didn't know.

Today I heard a native speaker use the word *aspect*, pronounced in a way that to me sounded like *aspé*, and I was surprised. Presumably if it was spelled *aspecte* the *ct* would not be silent? Is *ect* always silent at the end of a word? What about *ict, uct, oct, act*?

Comment: Le mot « compact » est prononcé /kɔ̃pakt/. ;)

Comment: For more surprises, see *distinct*: can be pronounced both ways, *succinct(e)*: you don't pronounce the "t" in the feminine, etc. :)

Comment: @guillaume31 As per Teleporting Goat's answer below, in "succincte" you pronounce the "t" but not the "c".

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch yes, thanks, I meant c.

Comment: As a side note, *aspect* sounds like *aspè* (with an e accent grave)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Narrowing it to -ect word final for the moment, some words ending in -ect are pronounced with the [ɛ] ending.  Your mileage may vary literally on regional aspects for some, the onset of the following word, and of course register (theatre, poetry, conversation, and what sound comes next in any given elocution).  A big one for [kt] is *correct* which may also end in [k].

Here's a group that usually ends in a vowel sound [ɛ] (see note on **-spect** below):

- respect
- aspect

Contrast with these which often end in [kt]:

- direct [diʀɛkt]
- intellect [ɛ̃telɛkt]
- abject [abʒɛkt]
- infect [ɛ̃fɛkt]

And some can go either way:

- circonspect siʀkɔ̃spɛ(kt), ɛkt
- suspect syspɛ(kt), ɛkt

Parts of speech and meaning matter.

Notable "exception" is *[correct](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Correct)*, which does pronounce the /ɛkt/ (or [k] regionally), but not ending in a vowel sound. A theory on the pronunciation from the Latin etymology comes from the Latin past participle *correctus*.

> Au XVIIe s. il y a hésitation au plur. et devant consonne du mot suiv. entre [εkt], [εk], [εt] et [ε]. La prononc. expressive en [-kt] devait l'emporter.

Many words that end in the vowel already lost the *c* spelling and [k] in some parts of speech or meaning but retain it in other inflections: objet, objectif, effet, effectuer.

---

### Note on **spect** and [ɛ]

There are about seven words that end in **-spect**, root *spec* from Latin (*specto, spectare, spectavi, spectatus* and *speciō, specere, spexi, spectum*).  Only one does not end in  [ɛ], *[anspect](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Anspect)*, a technical and rare word, exceptional to this root from a bit of a fluke, it alone ends in [k].

> PRONONC. : [ɑ̃spek]. Passy 1914 est le seul dict. à ne pas transcrire la finale [k] :  ɑ̃:spε. Mart. Comment prononce 1913, p. 216 fait observer : ,,il ne faut pas assimiler aux autres mots en -spect le mot technique anspec(t), terme de marine, qui n'a pris un t dans l'orthographe que par une fausse analogie avec les autres : c'est le seul mot où le c doive toujours se prononcer, et toujours seul.`` Accord également des dict. du xixes. pour la finale [k].

Otherwise, a mnemonic for words that do not pronounce the word final [kt] coda would be the root **-spect**: *aspect, circonspect, irrespect, prospect, respect*, and *suspect* all end in [ɛ].

Comment: We have _correct_ pronounced [k] regionally? _suspect_ IMHO is usually [ɛ], as well as _circonspect_. At least, that's the pronunciations I'm used to.

Comment: @Frank I have always heard *correct* pronounced [korɛkt] (young children might say [korɛk]) while *circonspect* is [siʀkɔ̃spɛ] or [siʀkɔ̃spe], *suspect* too.

Comment: @Frank C'est correc' has a different meaning, see https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43582/1893.  I do give [ɛ] as the first pronunciation of *suspect* and *circonspect*

Comment: By "some can go either way", do you mean in the feminine? Because as far as I know "suspect" and "circonspect" are never pronounced /syspɛkt/ and /siʀkɔ̃spɛkt/

Comment: Note that, in all *-ect* words that may be adjectives and therefore giving *-ecte* as feminine , "ct" is pronounced.

Comment: @Graffito that seems to contradict what Teleporting Goat and jiliagre say above, for _circonspect_ and _suspect_. Do you really mean to say that it is pronounced in all such _-ect_ words? Or do you mean that it is pronounced in the _-ecte_ forms?

Comment: @JamesMartin:  Good remark, the "ct" in suspect and circonspect (even they may be adjectives) is silent. the "rule" in my comment was wrong :(

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I'm not ready to discount the possibility of some facultative liaison somewhere out there.  I can't find a minimal pair rule or example that forbids it for *suspect* or *circonspect*.  Agreed that normally it's /ɛ̃/, including être suspect à qqun, I don't make a liaison there.

Comment: Oh wow I had no idea *respect* was pronounced this way.

Comment: @livresque Good job spotting that thing with *-spect*! I completely missed it ^^ Now there's a definite way to tell, apart from a couple rare exceptions

Answer (score 5):

Words in *-act* are always pronounced /akt/

> Artefact, contact, exact, impact, intact, tract

Words in *-ict* are pronounced /ikt/, except the rare *amict* (/a.mi/), that I didn't know before researching this topic.

> Addict, district, strict, verdict

Words in *-inct* are pronounced /ɛ̃/ (*-ct* is silent)

> distinct*, instinct, succinct

It's worth noting that the feminine *succincte* is /syk.sɛ̃t/ (the *c* is silent). For all the other words in *-ct*, the feminine *-cte* is pronounced /kt/ as expected.

For words in *-ect*, it depends. As mentioned by Livresque, words in *-ect* pronounced /ɛ/ usually lost their *c*, but some have resisted that change. These are pronounced /ɛ/:

> Aspect, circonspect, prospect, respect, suspect

While these are pronounced /ɛkt/:

> Abject, affect, correct, direct, infect, intellect, select (anglicism)

There are no words ending in *-uct* or *-oct* in French.

---

* For *distinct*, the pronunciation /distɛ̃kt/ can also be found sometimes.

Comment: Pour _distinct_, je prononce _ct_ et c'est la prononciation usuelle pour moi, même au masculin.